# Are the components of a Cauchy-Riemann mapping harmonic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of the plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and
>   let the mapping $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be
>    represented by $F(x, y) = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$ for $(x, y)$ in
>    $\mathcal{O}$. Then, we say the mapping $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is called a *Cauchy-Riemann mapping* provided that
>    each of the functions $u : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $v
>  : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has continuous second-order
>    partial derivatives and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x, y) =
>  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x, y) \hspace{1em} \text{ and }
>  \hspace{1em} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial
>  v}{\partial x}(x, y)$$
>
> for all $(x, y)$ in $\mathcal{O}$.

Is it necessarily true that $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ are harmonic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For instance, 
$$
 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 y} = 
   \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
=  \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y} - \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y} = 0.
$$
The calculation for $v$ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic.  Source: [Cartan's *Elementary Theory of Analytic Functions*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Elementary_Theory_of_Analytic_Functions.html?id=KsGbqTBjyoUC).